# Can't connect to SQL user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web-config, connection-string

Guys I am trying to host locally a asp website on my PC. Now the website works perfectly in VS2012's debug mode. Now I have published it and hosted it on IIS server 7.5 (using windows 7 x64), now when I browse localhost, the default login page of my site is shown. When I put login credentials and press login button, I get the following error : (error is generated whether the credentials are correct or not)

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\SILICON-PC$'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\SILICON-PC$'.

Stack Trace:


[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\SILICON-PC$'.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5352431
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +69
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +30
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +317
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +891
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +518
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +278
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +732
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +85
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1057
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +196
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
Logon.LookupUser(String Username) +87
Logon.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +48
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9752490
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +196
```

This is the connection string, I am using in web config.

```
<add name="ST" connectionString="Data Source=000.000.0.000,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=STDB;User ID=user;Password=pass" />
```

where `Data Source` has my PC's IP and SQL credentials are correct, I have checked. Also, I have a desktop application that is using the same credentials and is working perfectly.
I have also selected `NetworkService` in my application's pool identity from IIS manager.

What could be the problem?

Comment: The domain account WORKGROUP\SILICON-PC$ exists? If yes, then does the account have access to the Database . "I have also selected NetworkService" this woudl not work because you have chosen sql server authentication in the connection string and not windows (SSPI)

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the correct connection string??

Comment: @Rajatbanerjee Yes, My PC's name is Silicon-PC. It has SQL Server installed. What should I do to make the webpage connect to SQL server directly? Shouldn't we choose NetworkService if we want to connect to SQL server directly?

Comment: @VincentDagpin , does it matter ? because the user gets a authentication error which would come only if he was able to access the server? or....

Comment: @VincentDagpin I masked my PC's ip with 0s.

Comment: @User2012384 Yes, I am pretty sure. I check with `connectionstrings.com`

Comment: @user3331470 there would be 2 types of authentication in SQL server ...namely sql server authentication and Windows authentication ( more from a active directory prespective) . please go through some msdn article on how to provide access to a account on the particular server and then how to add the same account to the  security group for your database

Comment: @Rajatbanerjee If I choose ApplicationPoolIdentity in application pool's setting then the error changes to : "Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\mysite'."  mysite is the name of folder of my website in IIS manager.

Comment: @user3331470.. The iis and SQL server are on the same domain or the same box?

Comment: @user3331470 I mean, sometimes, you have several connection strings in one config file, and it might have a chance that you use the wrong one

Comment: @Rajatbanerjee SQL server and IIS are on same PC. Although I am connected to a domain, but I am not using it.

Comment: superb! Now set up your app pool with the user 'Silicon-PC\UserName' this user would be default user of the box(since you said you are not using the domain) . Next go to your  SSMS ->Security -> Login ..if the user is not present add the user, the under 'UserMappings' provide access to the db along with necessary rights . try logging into the db server with this user. you would have to change your connection string to use SSPI and not provide the credential's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create login for your machine, and add rights to read/write your database:

```
-- Create login
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [WORKGROUP\SILICON-PC$] FROM WINDOWS
GO


-- Add it as user of YourDatabase, and assign rights to read/write data using roles
USE [YourDatabase]
GO

CREATE USER [silicon-pc] FOR LOGIN [WORKGROUP\SILICON-PC$] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [silicon-pc] 
go

ALTER ROLE db_datawriter  ADD MEMBER [silicon-pc] 
go‏
```

Also you can use direct impersonation using login/password combination, another windows account, or certificate-based auth.